# Cerrar p-panel que se encuentra dentro de p-panel

Tags: angular, primeng

Para la aplicacion que estoy creando tengo que hacer una pagina donde se van a desplegar unos datos de liquidaciones. Para ello cree un p-panel grande que se puede cerrar y abrir y para cada liquidacion como se tiene que poder ver itemizada se me ocurrio hacer otro p-panel dentro de este p-panel grande. El problema llega que al momento de colapsar el p-panel chico este no llega a colapsar del todo y creo que esto se debe a que el p-panel grande tiene mayor prioridad sobre que se cierra o se abre.

[image: Asi es como queda al momento de cerrarlo]

Intente crear otra variable para que al momento de colapsarlo no afecte a las mismas variables pero el resultado fue el mismo.

```
<p-panel header="Liquidaciones a pagar:" class="d-block d-sm-none" [collapsed]="collapsed" (onToggle)="collapsed"
         [toggleable]="true" style="margin-top: 10px">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-l-2 col-m-2 col-s-5 mx-1">
    <div class="field flex-grow-1">
                <span class="p-float-label p-input-icon-left" style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 10px">
                    <input disabled type="text" id="inputtext-left" pInputText style="height:40px; width:100%">
                    <label for="inputtext-left">Matricula {{matricula}}</label>
                </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-9" style="color: #50535C;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 700;">
      Total a pagar en ARS
    </div>
    <div class="col-1" style="color: #50535C;text-align: right;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 600;">
      {{totalAPagar}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <p-button [disabled]="this.seleccionados.length == 0" icon="pi pi pi-dollar" label="Pagar"
              style="width: 100%"></p-button>
  </div>
  <p-carousel [value]="liquidacionesAMostrar" [numVisible]="liquidacionesAMostrar.length" orientation="vertical"
              [showIndicators]="false" [showNavigators]="false"
              [verticalViewPortHeight]="liquidacionesAMostrar.length.toString()+'00px'"
              style="margin-top: 10px">
    <ng-template let-dato pTemplate="item">
      <div class="dato-item">
        <div class="dato-item-content">
          <p-panel header="Liquidacion- {{dato.data.nroDoc}}"
                   [style]="{'margin-top':'10px'}" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="colapsado" (onToggle)="colapsado">
            <div>
              {{dato.data.subTotal}}
            </div>
          </p-panel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-carousel>
</p-panel>
```

Este es el html que tengo hasta ahora. Encontre algo sobre p-splitter pero no era lo que necesitaba ya que necesito poder cerrar el que se encuentra adentro de otro panel no ordenarlos uno al lado del otro